# VBA - Move selected row to a defined list

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA, and I have been searching a solution to my problem without ever finding the right answer. My goal is to move a project row when completed to a list that I named "completed projects"

I defined a group of cells `"Project_list"-$A$42:$AH$57` and another as `"Completed_Projects"-$A$59:$AH$65`. I want to move Projects (associated to rows) from a Project_list  to the end of the Completed_Projects list.
The macro needs to check that in my selection I have the right information in cells computed in column O and S (O(Status of project) cells = "Closed" and S (End date of project) <> "").

How to I make my macro check for those 2 arguments based on my selected row?

Comment: Can you post the code that you've attempted with? Maybe we can help you fix any issue/errors with it? It's not very likely that some one will write the code for you

Comment: `Sub ArchiveProject()

Dim rng As Range
Sel = Selection

    If Cells("O").Value = "Closed" And Cells("S").Value <> "" Then
    
            Sel.Cut
            Sel.Insert
              
    Else
        MsgBox "Please compute CCR Status and End Date"
    End If

End Sub`

I still have not figured how to do what I want after the If statement. My goal is to move it to the end of Completed_Projects list. I am still researching how to do that.

Comment: I have been trying to come with a solution and might have changed how I set everything but here is where I stand:

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to come with a solution and might have changed how I set everything but here is where I stand:

```
Sub Archive2()
  Dim Status As Range
  Dim EndDate As Range
  Dim ActiveCell As Range
 With Active.Selection = Selection

Set Status = Intersect(Selection, Columns("O:O"))
Set EndDate = Intersect(Selection, Columns("S:S"))
 End With
```

I am trying to make it so that my selection is my set row and columns O and S are my column where I need to check for my arguments.

```
If Status.Value = "Closed" And EndDate.Value <> "" Then

'still looking at where I will compute the row. probably another Worksheet.

Else: Status.Value = InputBox("ComputeDATA1") _
And EndDate.Value = InputBox("ComputeDATA2")

End If

End Sub
```